# Unhandled Exception Attempted to read or write protected memory unhandled exception

Tags: c#, visual-c++, com, wrapper

I have a c# wrapper on top of win32 files. That code has proper try catch bloack.
But when this error occurs I just breaks there and never goes to catch block?

Detailed error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in abc.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Comment: Not so clear what the code looks like and where the exception originated.  AVE is a "critical" exception that you can't catch, google "HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute".  Or you plain asked the debugger to stop on unmanaged exceptions and forgot to turn it off.

Comment: Thanks [System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute()] fixed it...please add as post I will mark it as answer

Comment: You almost certainly should *never* do this.  This indicates that it is .NET itself that is corrupted instead of unmanaged memory.  Continuing to run with a corrupted GC heap is a drastically bad idea.  You must fix the bug.

Comment: @HansPassant That's utter nonsense. It in no way indicates that .net itself is corrupted. Test it with this code in an unsafe function `int result = *(int*)(0x0)` and explain to me what is "corrupted" in the runtime. The error is as stated: Attempted to read or write protected memory. Nothing more.